# RedirectToAction called twice issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, redirect

I have the controllers:

```
Controller A
{
   public ActionResult ExecuteSomeStuff()
   {
    ....use TempData
    returns a View("StuffMade", SomeModel);
   }
}
```

and

```
 Controller B
{
   public ActionResult DoStuff()
   {
         ...fill up TempData     


    returns RedirectToAction("ExecuteSomeStuff", "A");
   }
}
```

The problem is that the ExecuteSomeStuff method on controller A is executed twice.
I dont need the actual redirect to be made, I just want the result(the view) from the ExecuteSomeStuff method to be returned for DoStuff method.
I dont want to have a reference to controller A in controller B in order to call the method directly.

Is there any way to do this without the physical redirect or new reference to be made to controller A in controller B??

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, instead of a `RedirectToAction`, you can return the ExecuteSomeStuff `View` from Controller B. You will need to be able to set the `Model` to pass into the View from Controller B. So you may still need to make some reference to the methods used in Controller A.

```
Controller B:
 {

    public ActionResult DoStuff()
    {
    ...fill up TempData 
    //set the model then Return the View with the Model passed in
    return View("ExecuteSomeStuff","A",SomeModel);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

This will look for a `View` with the same name as the action *ExecuteSomeStuff* without actually entering the *ExecuteSomeStuff* action. If your View has a different name, you can explicity specify the View to return like this:

```
return View("../A/theCorrectView.aspx", model);
```

Comment: I did that and it throws and exception : "The relative virtual path 'ExecuteSomeStuff.aspx' is not allowed here", so I dont think it reaches the ExecuteSomeStuff action method.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't execute the ExecuteSomeStuff action. I thought that was the original idea. I updated my answer. Which version of MVC are you using? I've tested this and it works in MVC3. It should work in MVC 2 as well.